# Blank Screen Issue initially from booting

Tags: boot

I would like to discuss an issue I'm experiencing with my Ubuntu 22.04 LTS version. I use my laptop directly with an AC adapter, without the battery. The problem arises when I turn on my laptop; it doesn't display the company logo, and the screen remains blank. Even when the option appears to "press the F1 key to continue," it doesn't show up on the screen. I have to press the F1 key blindly. The computer seems to boot perfectly in the background, and I can log in to my Ubuntu OS, although throughout the process, the screen remains blank. Everything seems to be working fine behind this blank screen. Interestingly, unplugging the AC adapter and plugging it in again, repeating this 2 to 4 times, temporarily resolves the issue. However, the problem recurs the next day. Occasionally, the company logo shows, but not consistently. I'm uncertain about the root cause of this problem. Please provide guidance on how to address this issue.

Comment: If the screen is always blank from power on, exactly how is it working?  This is a hardware fault. If you are lucky, maybe just a loose connection inside.

Comment: Performing 2 to 3 sudden shutdowns by unplugging the charger resolves it, but only temporarily. For instance, the next day, when I turn it on again, the screen becomes blank. However, I want to clarify that only the screen is blank; the system is working correctly. I can log in to my OS. Sometimes, when I lock my screen and then unlock it, the blank screen issue resolves, and sometimes it doesn't resolve my issue. I'm unsure if this is a hardware issue, a software-related problem, or a BIOS problem.

Comment: I have offered additional clarification. Could you now please inform me whether this is solely a hardware issue or if there are other factors involved? Is this a serious problem or not ???? When my laptop working fine and i restart it it restarts correctly without blank screen

Comment: The BIOS and Ubuntu don't rely on each other at all for graphics output, yet they are both affected the same.  It's the graphics hardware.  The things you are trying have an effect on internal temperatures, which can influence poor connections, or failing electronics.